# Interface 'Silex\ServiceProviderInterface' not found

Tags: php, silex

I am new to silex, uploadcare and github. I am taking a tutorial on youtube about uploading images to my social network site. 
But I keep getting this error.

Here is some of my code.

```
namespace KLEIDDER\Providers;


use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;

class UploadcareProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app['uploadcare'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {

            return new \Uploadcare\Api('6854166a3c2cd467beb8', '416e1509f07b6b17cbe0');

        });

    }
    public  function boot(Application $app)
    {


    }

}
```

from the index.php page

```
$app->register(new KLEIDDER\Providers\UploadcareProvider);

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {

    var_dump($app['uploadcare']);
    die();
```

I've recently been told that I should use Pimple, so i tried that

```
namespace KLEIDDER\Providers;


use Silex\Application;
use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;

class UploadcareProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
public function register(Application $app)
{
    $app['uploadcare'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {

        return new \Uploadcare\Api('6854166a3c2cd467beb8', '416e1509f07b6b17cbe0');

    });

}
public  function boot(Application $app)
{


}
```

}

But now i get this error, Fatal error: Declaration of KLEIDDER\Providers\UploadcareProvider::register() must be compatible with Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface::register(Pimple\Container $pimple)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you've got Silex 1.x code, and have Silex 2.x installed.

It between versions `ServiceProviderInterface` shifted out of Silex, and you need to use Pimple's one instead:

`use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;`

Update for follow-up problem.

Obviously `Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface` is not identical to `Silex\ServiceProviderInterface`, so you will need to recode your class accordingly. The chief difference is the method signature for the `register` method has equivalently changed. Under Silex it was:

[`public function register(Silex\Application $app)`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/v1.3.5/src/Silex/ServiceProviderInterface.php#L27)

Now using Pimple's one it is:

[`public function register(Container $pimple)`](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/blob/master/src/Pimple/ServiceProviderInterface.php#L45)

Fortunately PHP gives an error message telling you exactly what's wrong if one tries to continue using the Silex version of the method signature ;-)

Also note that Pimple's ServiceProviderInterface no long needs that `boot` method either.

Docs:
[Silex / Providers > Creating a provider](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers.html#creating-a-provider)

Comment: Thank You Adam, but now I'm getting this, Declaration of KLEIDDER\Providers\UploadcareProvider::register() must be compatible with Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface::register(Pimple\Container $pimple)

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what the problem is. I don't mean to be obtuse, but did you actually *read it*?